# Land use GIS data for California for the year 2018

Tags: data-request, usa, data

I am looking for land use data (not land cover), preferably in a raster format with at least 100m resolution or higher for California for the year 2018. Are there such data?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "land use" - what sort of categories are you interested in? Would something like [this](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=fc92d38533d440078f17678ebc20e8e2) be suitable? Note there is a link to an updated version of the downloader.

Comment: By land use I mean for example categories such as residential, factories, businesses etc. The link you provided I think shows land cover.

Comment: The land use you describe cannot be remotely sensed, unlike land cover which at least can distinguish between built area, crops, trees, etc. You may struggle to find a product at that resolution that splits "built area" into more specific categories.

Comment: There is such a product for India (https://resourcewatch.org/data/explore/cit049-Urban-Land-Use-India_1?section=Discover&selectedCollection=&zoom=3&lat=0&lng=0&pitch=0&bearing=0&basemap=dark&labels=light&layers=%255B%257B%2522dataset%2522%253A%2522e354f7b8-0fca-422f-bf12-fc6189812bec%2522%252C%2522opacity%2522%253A1%252C%2522layer%2522%253A%25228efadc4d-7663-4666-ae69-fdf2dccd0cbd%2522%257D%255D&aoi=&page=1&sort=most-viewed&sortDirection=-1). But I guess you are right, I couldn't find for USA and I am looking for several days now.